# Iterm2 - Export a single profile's settings for distribution to others

Tags: terminal, preferences, iterm

I've been getting used to working with Iterm2 over the past few weeks. I have a very specific profile configuration requirement for a legacy business application. The configuration for the profile requires a special font as well as keybinding and color changes.

I've been able to encapsulate all of these changes into a discrete Iterm2 profile. However, I'd like to export the settings for this profile and distribute them to end-users.

I know that it's possible to export a .plist file with all of the Iterm preferences, but I'd like this to be separate so that other people can import without impacting other potentially extant profiles.

Are there any clean options for this?

---

[image]

Comment: I don't think iTerm has this functionality built into it, but my approach would be to write a Python script to write the profile into the user's iTerm preferences. Each profile is just a dictionary inside an array called (strangely) "New Bookmarks". Python's plistlib is ideal for doing that.

Comment: So essentially, I'd need to write an installer?

Comment: If you want it to look like an installer pkg, you could use this: http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2014/03/08/payload-free-package-creator-app/

Comment: But it could also just be an executable script for the user to  double click.

Comment: The profile file is XML -- you could export, edit it in an text editor, and ship an XML file with just the one profile you want in it.